# Unable to sort the dictionary of list by keys alphabetically using the lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dict of list

```
Dict = {'Language': ['german', 'hindi', 'arabic', 'spanish'], 'Auto': ['porsche', 'bmw', 'jaguar', 'chrysler'], 'Mobile': ['nokia', 'apple', 'asus', 'samsung']}
```

and after sorting the dict by values, I expect the o/p to be:

```
{'Language': ['arabic', 'german', 'hindi', 'spanish'], 'Auto': ['bmw', 'chrysler', 'jaguar', 'porsche'], 'Mobile': ['apple', 'asus', 'nokia', 'samsung']}
```

where all the list elements get sorted alphabetically. I tried using the lambda function inside the sorted function but it isn't working. Hence can someone please take a look and correct this tiny piece of code of mine..

```
sorted(Dict.items(), key = lambda t: t[1][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with dictionary comprehension

**Ex.**

```
dict1 = {'Language': ['german', 'hindi', 'arabic', 'spanish'], 'Auto': ['porsche', 
        'bmw', 'jaguar', 'chrysler'], 'Mobile': ['nokia', 'apple', 'asus', 
        'samsung']}

reuslt = { k: sorted(v) for k,v in dict1.items() }
print(reuslt)
```

Or map with lambda

```
reuslt  = dict(map(lambda kv: (kv[0], sorted(kv[1])), dict1.items()))
print(reuslt)
```

**O/P:**

```
{'Language': ['arabic', 'german', 'hindi', 'spanish'], 'Auto': ['bmw', 'chrysler',
   'jaguar', 'porsche'], 'Mobile': ['apple', 'asus', 'nokia', 'samsung']}
```

Comment: is the sorting not possible with lambda?